# fadein() and fadeout() using with setinterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello freinds how can i make folowing code working with `fadein()` `fadeout()` effect
i want the every next number come with `fadein()` effect and current number go with `fadeout()` effect . can i make it in loop .. like if last number is `fadeout()` after that first number is `fadein()` . like loop

```
<script>    
var counter = 1;
    $(function() {
      incrementCounter();
    });

    function incrementCounter() {
      $('#fade').html(counter);
      counter++;
      if (counter < 4) {
        setTimeout(incrementCounter, 2000);
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do a check on `counter` like this:

```
function incrementCounter() {
  $('#fade').html(counter);
  counter++;
  if(counter%2)
      $('#fade').fadeOut();
  else
      $('#fade').fadeIn();

  if (counter < 4) {
    setTimeout(incrementCounter, 2000);
  }
}
```

or you could also do the check if the target is visible

```
function incrementCounter() {
  $('#fade').html(counter);
  counter++;
  if($('#fade').is(":visible"))
      $('#fade').fadeOut();
  else
      $('#fade').fadeIn();

  if (counter < 4) {
    setTimeout(incrementCounter, 2000);
  }
}
```